# Meaning of electrochemical vs nonelectrochemical steps

Tags: reaction-mechanism, electrochemistry, catalysis

Can someone please explain to me what is meant by an electrochemical reaction step and how it differs from a nonelectrochemical reaction step in the same overall reaction in the context of electrocatalysis?

A simple example with H2 or H2O would be sufficient.

Comment: $\ce{H^+ + OH^- <=> H2O}$ is a "nonelectrochemical" reaction step

Comment: And electrolysis of $\ce{H2SO4}$ in water is electrochemical. See http://www.bbc.co.uk/schools/gcsebitesize/science/add_gateway_pre_2011/periodictable/electrolysisrev2.shtml

Comment: @MaxW can you please elaborate why it is not an electrochemical step. To me it seems that two charged species interacted. This is the confusing part for me. Is there a definition one can use?